# How to install Wordpress from hosting service with mysql database from Compute Engine GCP?

Tags: mysql, google

I own a wordpress website (website.com) that running well with hosting service (cpanel). So i want to create a new subdomain (new.website.com) and install wordpress in there but for the database i want to use Compute Engine from Google Cloud Platform.

I already install mysql on the CE and running perfectly, but unfortunately i couldn't connect it to my hosting service to install wordpress.

how can i do this?

what i already tried:

1. create mysql on CE (running with ssh)
2. create database, create user(connect to web ip), and password
3. changing the my.cnf (change the bind-address to 0.0.0.0)
4. setting up wp-config installation on file manager on my hosting service, such as: database_name,user,password, and host
5. connect the database from CE to mysql client (mysql workbench)
6. make sure the port open: 3306

output:
"error establishing a database connection" when i try new.website.com

potentially to be the problem:

1. the mysql, i couldn't retrieve the database ip, cs when i run "mysql> status" it would return: connection: Localhost via UNIX socket
2. the wp-config setup, do i need to change the db_host? i thought it should be the database ip, but i couldn't get the ip.

cheers from indonesia.

Comment: Hi Rio! This is more of a problem to do with setting up a MySQL server than it is to do with Wordpress specifically. You may have more luck posting on e.g. ServerFault where you might get more specialised answers for MySQL.

Comment: I searched for 'GCP make mysql public' and found this. Did you do all the steps here? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-ip

Comment: @mozboz thanks for the recommendation, i'll bring this issue there, thanks. I did check that page, but thats for Cloud SQL, meanwhile mine is mysql that runs in CE